# Delivery Status Notification (Relay) in Exchange Server 2007 with original email attachment

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2003

I have recently setup Exhchange Server 2007. The server is smarthosting outgoing messages. Users have 'request delivery receipt' on  by default for their 'auditing' purposes in Outlook.

They would like the original email attached to the delivery notification  as was the case in Exchange Server 2003.  Ex 2007 does not attach the original message in the delivery notification.  I need this same functionality in 2007!  The question has been asked [here](http://forums.msexchange.org/m_1800548219/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#1800548219), [here](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/exchange-2007-delivery-status-notification-relay-message/) and [here](http://forums.msexchange.org/m_1800539602/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#1800539602) but cannot find a valid solution.

[Here's some information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/0ae423cc-82c3-4e80-8d45-0c4d6643736e) about the functionality in Exchange 2003.
The question is, can i replication this functionality in 2007?
Here is what a 2007 delivery message looks like:
[image]

I know it's possible to customize DSN's.  Can I make a custom DSN for this type of message and have the original included as an attachment?
Anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are some relevant DSN commands on the `Set-TransportConfig` cmdlet ([TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124151(EXCHG.80).aspx)) and in particular `Set-TransportConfig -DSNConversionMode DoNotConvert`.

This exchange [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2008/12/11/3406622.aspx) explains the functionality a bit better. This will be for Exchange 2007 SP1 RU4 onwards.

I've not had chance to try it out, but hope it helps.

Comment: entertaining post maybe, useful for my problem?  <i>The DSNConversionMode parameter controls how Exchange handles DSNs that are generated by earlier versions of Exchange or non-Exchange messaging systems</i> the DSN is being generated by my exhchange server, but I want it to include the original message